# Htaccess file issue occurring

Tags: .htaccess

I am attempting to assign a root directory to a sub-sub domain however I am having no luck. My subdomain is sub2.sub1.example.com and I am trying to assign the directory to a directory inside the sub1 directory, however it will not work!

My `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.gaming.basickiwi.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ basickiwi.com/gaming/dev/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Share your code from the file

Comment: 'RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.gaming.basickiwi.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://basickiwi.com/gaming/dev/$1 [L,NC,QSA]'

Comment: http://dev.gaming.basickiwi.com is the domain I would like to have a folder, however it is returning a 404 / error

Comment: Please add your code to the question in future. Comments do not give much room for displaying code.

Comment: Is `basickiwi.com` a directory underneath your public document root? And where is your `.htaccess` file saved?

Comment: My .htaccess is saved in the root directory, and yes, basickiwi.com/index.php is in the main root.